# Toggle switch field with middle state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question if anyone was able to implement a toggle switch field with the middle state in ReactJS. I would need something like shown in the picture. I looked everywhere for a solution, but could not find any. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a switcher to have 3 states?

Comment: Yes, unselected, selectedTrue and selectedFalse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661970/3-state-css-toggle-switch/23662156#23662156