# Toggle between radio values when DIV is clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 state radio button.

The initial state is undetermined, Then you can disable/enable it.

The problem is when you click over the DIV. It always gets the first radio button value (OFF in this case). I would like to toggle between ON/OFF.
If you click on the labels it works correctly.

```css
.element-toggle-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.element-toggle-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: background 0.25s;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.element-toggle-switch:before,
.element-toggle-switch:after {
  content: "";
}

.element-toggle-checkbox.disabled~.element-toggle-switch,
.element-toggle-checkbox:disabled~.element-toggle-switch {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: .65;
}

.element-toggle-switch:before {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.25s;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
}

.element-toggle-container:hover .element-toggle-switch:before {
  background: #fff;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="na"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="na"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 0.9375rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="off"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #ff0f0f;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="on"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #56c080;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="on"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 1.6875rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label for="element-1-off">No</label>
<label class="element-toggle-container">
  <input class="element-toggle-checkbox not_uniform" id="element-1-off" value="off" name="element-1" type="radio" />
  <input class="element-toggle-checkbox not_uniform" id="element-1-na" value="na" name="element-1" type="radio" checked="checked" />
  <input class="element-toggle-checkbox not_uniform" id="element-1-on" value="on" name="element-1" type="radio"  />
  <div class="element-toggle-switch"></div>
</label>
<label for="element-1-on">Yes</label>
```

Comment: Please don't use external code sites to represent code that can easily be presented as a Stack snippet.

Comment: @connexo Sorry, I'm not used to ask in SO :)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://code-boxx.com/pure-simple-css-toggle-button/

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner The problem is that I need 3 states :)

Comment: Then see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661970/3-state-css-toggle-switch

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Thanks but it is not exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to toggle the value when you click over the "switch", in this example you need to click on the label.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `.element-toggle-container` is a `<label>` element without a `for` specified and it has the `<input>` elements as children. This means it will relate to the first `<input>` child, which in this case is the 'off' button. Why not remove the `.element-toggle-container` altogether and extend the labels of the 'on' and 'off' buttons like in the example below?

```css
label[for="element-1-off"],
label[for="element-1-on"] { 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: .1rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

label[for="element-1-off"] {
  padding-right: 1.15rem;
  left: 0;
}

label[for="element-1-on"] {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  left: 3.5rem;
}

.toggle-switch {
  position:relative;
}

.element-toggle-switch {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: background 0.25s;
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.element-toggle-switch:before,
.element-toggle-switch:after {
  content: "";
}

.element-toggle-checkbox.disabled~.element-toggle-switch,
.element-toggle-checkbox:disabled~.element-toggle-switch {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: .65;
}

.element-toggle-switch:before {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.25s;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
}

.element-toggle-container:hover .element-toggle-switch:before {
  background: #fff;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="na"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="na"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 0.9375rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="off"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #ff0f0f;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="on"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #56c080;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="on"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 1.6875rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-switch">
  <input class="element-toggle-checkbox not_uniform" id="element-1-off" value="off" name="element-1" type="radio" />
  <input class="element-toggle-checkbox not_uniform" id="element-1-na" value="na" name="element-1" type="radio" checked="checked" />
  <input class="element-toggle-checkbox not_uniform" id="element-1-on" value="on" name="element-1" type="radio"  />
  <label for="element-1-off">No</label>
  <div class="element-toggle-switch"></div>
  <label for="element-1-on">Yes</label>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -3):

```
.element-toggle-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.element-toggle-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: background 0.25s;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.element-toggle-switch:before,
.element-toggle-switch:after {
  content: "";
}

.element-toggle-checkbox.disabled~.element-toggle-switch,
.element-toggle-checkbox:disabled~.element-toggle-switch {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: .65;
}

.element-toggle-switch:before {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.25s;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
}

.element-toggle-container:hover .element-toggle-switch:before {
  background: #fff;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="na"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="na"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 0.9375rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="off"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #ff0f0f;
}
.element-toggle-checkbox[value="off"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 0.2375rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="on"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch {
  background: #56c080;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox[value="on"]:checked~.element-toggle-switch:before {
  left: 1.6875rem;
}

.element-toggle-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  
}
```

Comment: can you give an explanation?